# Use common expression language to limit a permissions to a specific workflow

Tags: github, google-cloud-platform, github-actions, openid-connect, workload-identity

I am creating a workflow identity federation pool provider and I want to specify the permissions of the service account that will be used so as to be leveraged only from a specific workflow file.

In the GHA OIDC [fields](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/security-hardening-your-deployments/about-security-hardening-with-openid-connect#understanding-the-oidc-token), the example is the following:

```
  "job_workflow_ref": "octo-org/octo-automation/.github/workflows/oidc.yml@refs/heads/main",
```

I want however to allow all branches.

Is this possible using the common expression language?

Will something like this work?

```
attribute_condition  = "(assertion.repository=='MyOrg/MyRepo' && assertion.job_workflow_ref=='MyOrg/MyRepo/.github/workflows/myworkflow.yaml*')"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`google/cel-spec`](https://github.com/google/cel-spec) used by GCP does not seem to support wildcards.

Instead, you can try and test the `startsWith` function to achieve the same result:

```
attribute_condition  = "(assertion.repository=='MyOrg/MyRepo' && assertion.job_workflow_ref.startsWith('MyOrg/myrepo/.github/workflows/myworkflow.yaml'))"
```

That is:

`attribute_condition  = "(assertion.repository=='MyOrg/MyRepo' && assertion.job_workflow_ref.startsWith('MyOrg/myrepo/.github/workflows/myworkflow.yaml'))"`

This condition will ensure that the repository is "`MyOrg/MyRepo`" and that the `job_workflow_ref` starts with the specified workflow file path.

Since the branch information comes after the workflow file path, this condition will allow all branches.

---

Alternatively, you can also try and test the `in` operator as a workaround to check if the workflow file path is contained in the job_workflow_ref string

```
attribute_condition  = "(assertion.repository=='MyOrg/MyRepo' && (assertion.event_name=='pull_request' || assertion.event_name=='workflow_dispatch') && 'MyOrg/MyRepo/.github/workflows/myworkflow.yaml' in assertion.job_workflow_ref)"
```

That is:

`attribute_condition  = "(assertion.repository=='MyOrg/MyRepo' && (assertion.event_name=='pull_request' || assertion.event_name=='workflow_dispatch') && 'MyOrg/MyRepo/.github/workflows/myworkflow.yaml' in assertion.job_workflow_ref)"`

This condition ensures that the repository is "`MyOrg/MyRepo`", the event is either "`pull_request`" or "`workflow_dispatch`", and the workflow file path is included in the `job_workflow_ref`.
This should allow all branches that use the specified workflow.

Comment: Any idea why am I getting [this](https://gist.github.com/pantelis-karamolegkos/1df77fc6ed9b44806fc8a37698422332) error?

Comment: @pkaramol Maybe because `startsWith` ([that I saw here](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Agoogle%2Fcel-spec+startswith&type=code)) is not available in this context. Try instead `attribute_condition  = "(assertion.repository=='MyOrg/MyRepo' && (assertion.event_name=='pull_request' || assertion.event_name=='workflow_dispatch') && 'MyOrg/MyRepo/.github/workflows/myworkflow.yaml' in assertion.job_workflow_ref)"`

Comment: ok thanks that worked, you may want to update your answer as well

Comment: @pkaramol Perfect, well done. I have updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Sorry for being such a pain, but for the sake of completeness and for people who may stumble upon this at some point in time, here is the correct syntax for the `startsWith` function: `assertion.job_workflow_ref.startsWith('MyOrg/myrepo/.github/workflows/myworkflow.yaml')`

Comment: @pkaramol do you mean you did not use the in operator? Or that the startwith is also working?

Comment: It was a matter of syntax. Check [here](https://gist.github.com/pantelis-karamolegkos/78f9e9fdaaed847057c4258126e68207)

Comment: @pkaramol Very clear, thank you. I have edited the answer accordingly.